# What does intelligence do in middle manager of justice?

Tags: middle-manager-of-justice

In middle manager of justice, what does intelligence do?

Comment: I cannot create a new tag so I had to just use iOS, please don't down vote me for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I played it -- it kind of got boring fast -- but as I recall it determines the amount of special attack power points the hero has. More points mean more uses of their special attacks.